# NginX - Define a global variable with random number as value

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I need a variable in http block with a random number as value.

How can we define a variable in http block, whose value is computed from a function? I tried calling function inside map directive, but that prints the function call as a literal. I explored lua, but cannot find a way. Please assist.

Comment: share your code...

Comment: Do you want that variable will get random value upon start or for every request?